# RecordNotFound error when using create action on form with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This problem has been bothering me for a while, and I cannot seem to find any (working) answer to the issue.

So, basically the problem is that when I attempt to submit the form to the database, instead of inserting the data I have entered into the fields belonging to the nested attributes (basic_details_set) it seems to search that specific table for a row with a matching ID.

**This is the error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#create
Couldn't find BasicDetailsSet with ID=1 for Page with ID=1
```

**Page Model:**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :dealership, { :optional => false }
      has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users

      has_one :basic_details_set
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :basic_details_set
end
```

**Basic Details Set Model:**

```
class BasicDetailsSet < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :page
end
```

**Page controller:**

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'

  before_action :find_dealership

  def index
      @pages = @dealership.pages.sorted
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
      @page = Page.new(:dealership_id => @dealership.id)
      @page.build_basic_details_set
  end

  def create
      @page = Page.new(page_params)
      @page.save
  end

  def edit
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update

  end

  def delete

  end

  def destroy

  end

  private
  def find_dealership
      @dealership = Dealership.find(params[:dealership_id])
  end

  def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:id, :permalink, :active, :dealership_id, basic_details_set_attributes: [:id, :price])
  end

  end
```

**Form partial:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID:</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:id) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Link:</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:permalink) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Aktiv:</th>
    <td><%= f.check_box(:active) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Forhandler ID:</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:dealership_id) %></td>
</tr>

<%= f.fields_for :basic_details_set do |p| %>
<tr>
    <th>ID:</th>
    <td><%= p.text_field(:id) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Pris:</th>
    <td><%= p.text_field(:price) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**new.html.erb:**

```
<div>
<h2>Ny Side</h2>

<%= form_for(@page, :url => pages_path(:dealership_id => @dealership.id)) do |f| %>

<%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>

<div><%= f.submit("Opret Side") %></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Link to view all of a given Dealership's pages (inside views/dealerships/index)**

```
<%= link_to("Vis sider", pages_path(:dealership_id => dealership.id), :class => 'action show') %>
```

**Show action used in the link above**

```
  def show
  @dealership = Dealership.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'dealerships#index'

resources :dealerships do
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end

resources :pages do
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end

end
```

Any ideas for why this is happening and potentially how to fix it?

Comment: post your complete controller, it seems like you have some before actions that is doing something, please add the complete controller to see

Comment: @xploshioOn Thanks for the reply. I've added the full code for the controller now. Do you suspect it's the before action that's causing the issue?

Comment: ok cool, now add the routes file and how are you accesing to that page, if it's a link, then paste the code, if you are just putting the url in the browser, then maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @xploshioOn Should all be there now at the bottom of the post. I'm using a link from the Dealerships index to go to the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your problem is here on this part of the form

```
<%= f.fields_for :basic_details_set do |p| %>
<tr>
    <th>ID:</th>
    <td><%= p.text_field(:id) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Pris:</th>
    <td><%= p.text_field(:price) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

it seems like you are creating a nested resource, but you don't need to add the id text field, because on the create, the id will be filled by default.

if you pass an id here, it will try to update that ID and for the moment, it doesn't exist, so just remove the id field from the form and everything will work good.

Comment: That did remove the RecordNotFound error. However, the fields are not saving to the database. If I remove the only other field for basic_details_set (:price), then the page saves successfully. But with that field present, neither record is saved. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: Scratch that, I managed to fix it by adding 'required: false' to the BasicDetailsSet model. Thank you for your help!